# SVN server with LDAP athentication SASL error

Tags: apache-2.2, ldap, svn

i'm having few problems with my SVN authentication with Active Directory. I am using CollabNet subversion server + client on a windows server 2003 box.

When I try to connect to SVN from my computer I get

> SASL authentication error SASL(-13): generic failure: Unable to find a
>   callback: 2

My server access logs are empty too.

Here's my configuration :

httpd.conf

```
LoadModule ldap_module   modules/mod_ldap.so
LoadModule authnz_ldap_module   modules/mod_authnz_ldap.so
LoadModule authz_svn_module   modules/mod_authz_svn.so

<Location /svn>
DAV svn
SVNParentPath C:\SVN
AuthzSVNAccessFile C:/SVN/conf/access.txt
AuthzLDAPAuthoritative off
AuthType Basic
AuthBasicProvider ldap
AuthName "....corp"
AuthLDAPBindDN "admin account"
AuthLDAPBindPassword "password"
AuthLDAPURL "ldap://....?sAMAccountName?sub?(objectClass=*)"
Require valid-user
</Location>
```

access.txt:

```
[/]
* = rw
```

svnserve.conf:

```
anon-access = read
auth-access = write

use-sasl = true
min-encryption = 128
max-encryption = 256
```

Comment: `sasl.h` states that the error constant `-13` is `SASL_BADAUTH`.  [More verbosely](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sasl_errors): authentication failure.  This might mean that your `AuthLDAPBindDN` and/or `AuthLDAPBindPassword` are incorrect.  Try binding with [ldapsearch](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ldapsearch) from `openldap-clients` (for instance) to test.

Comment: In AuthLDAPBindDN I puted the complete distinguished name. And for the password im sure a 100% that it is the right one. I tried to bind JXplorer and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Do you use both svnserve and mod_dav_svn at the same time? Because httpd.conf is used by apache and svnserve.conf is used by svnserve demon. They are two different and independent files.

> I tried to bind JXplorer and it worked

What type of url have you used **http**://svn.example.net or **svn**://svn.example.net ?